# g_signal_connect()

Tags: gtk+, g-signal-connect

Подскажите, может ли быть с одним сигналом виджета связано несколько обработчиков?

Я имею в виду, корректно ли:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(widget), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(func_1), NULL);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(widget), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(func_2), NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно может, код корректен.

Можно даже полагаться на то, что обработчики будут вызываться в порядке соединения.

см. [документацию по сигналам](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/2.56/gobject-Signals.html#gobject-Signals.description)

Comment: А где описано это поведение? Я что-то не нашел...

Comment: то что можно присоединять несколько обработчиков на один сигнал — ИМХО само собой разумеющийся факт для абстракции «сигнала»... про порядок вызова — есть по ссылке: «*The user-provided signal handlers are called in the order they were connected in.*»